# TADO recordset XML to TClientDataSet XML format

Tags: delphi, tclientdataset

I'm saving **TADO recordset** to  **XML** 
and trying to load it to **TClientDataSet** but geting error about wrong XML format.

How can i transform ADO XML recordset format to TClientDataset format.

thanks.

Comment: Have you tried [`this example`](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=1498) or what is your code ?

Comment: @TLama The XML format used by ADO is no the same of the `TClientDataSet`

Answer (score 4):

The XML format used by the `TClientDataSet` is not the same used by ADO, in order to transform the XML ADO format in a valid XML file used by TClientDataset you have two options.

1) Use a XSLT Transformation, for this you need the a XSL Style Sheet and/or a XSD schema from XML , [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/492198/anyone-that-has-a-partial-xsd-that-describes-the-metadata-section-of-delphi-tcli) you find some hints  about the XSD.

2) Use one of the ado components to read the XML ADO file, then iterate over the records and finally populate the TClientDataSet.