# Insufficient memory with Delphi ClientDataSet.SaveToFile

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, firedac, tclientdataset

I need to generate an XML file from a table with 500.000 rows and 200 columns using Firedac Query and ClientDataSet to record ClientDataSet.SaveToFile.

```
ClientDataSet.Close;
Query.Sql.Clear;
Query.Sql.Add ("Select * from something");
ClientDataSet.Open;
ClientDataSet.SaveToFile("destination_folder.xml");
```

But to save the file with SaveToFile is the insufficient memory error.

How could I save this file? There is a way to write to multiple files the ClientDataSet already loaded?

Best regards.

Comment: standard cds/midas wasn't designed well to handle such amount of records. can't you avoid using cds in your scenario at all? do you really need that datapacket saved in midas xml format?

Comment: I need to write the XML file in the ClientDataSet recording format.

Comment: I'm afraid without rewriting its internals you won't be able to overcome its inherent problems. another idea would be to manually produce that file with your own code, you may want to see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/492198/anyone-that-has-a-partial-xsd-that-describes-the-metadata-section-of-delphi-tcli

Comment: Thanks for your comment @vavan.